# Copy data from a number of rows and specified columns to a sheet in new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The below code selects every 9998 rows, creates a new Excel sheet and then pastes the content.

1) I need to give a common heading to all the new Excel files. The cell values should start from A2.

2) I don't want to select the entire row, just column A and column C.

3) I want to change the sheet name in new Excel workbook that's been created.

```
Sub test() 

Dim lastRow As Long, myRow As Long, myBook As Workbook

lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For myRow = 2 To lastRow Step 9998

    Set myBook = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(myRow & ":" & myRow +9997).EntireRow.Copy myBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

Next myRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to put source columns A & C into target columns A & C or into target columns A & B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastRow As Long, myRow As Long, myBook As Workbook

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For myRow = 2 To lastRow Step 9998
            Set myBook = Workbooks.Add
            .Range("A" & myRow & ":C" & myRow + 9997).Copy myBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "New Name"
        Next myRow
    End With
End Sub
```

1) This is being resolved by simply changing your paste range to .Range("A2")

2) I changed your Copy range to only select columns A-C

3) Sheet name change happens in the last line of code (just before "Next myRow")

Hope it helps!